# Why was "Multiple config.ru files and nginx/passenger" deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I just noticed this post was deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010309/multiple-config-ru-files-and-nginx-passenger

I found this by googling for a problem I had. And this question is nearly the same as the problem I have right now. But the question is deleted. There is no indication that it was closed as off-topic or migrated, it was simply "Deleted by Community♦ Jan 27 at 2:11", and I can't find a post with a similar title on serverfault or anywhere else either.

Anyone know why this was deleted? I'm especially curious why it was deleted by Community. Could this deletion be the result of some automatic process?

Comment: Automatic system process that delete questions with no upvotes after they are not active for a while

Comment: Ah! Thanks. And this is definitely a dupe, added my own close vote.

Comment: Cheers, though I think it's better if some message will appear in the question revisions in such case. Feature request, anyone? :)