# Regular (non-moderator) users should be able to override deletions by Community user

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, community-user

There is a question on [Judaism.SE](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26630/by-mishloach-manos) that got deleted by the Community user. This question isn't *terrible* (we have worse one's there), and **I'm not complaining about this question in particular**.

I wanted to vote to undelete it. However, it says "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted". This "moderator" is Community!

I understand if a "real" live human moderator (no offense to all non-humans out here) deleted this question that we can't override it. But this is a Robot! It sees that it got a downvote, no answer and little activity for a while and just deletes it.

Can we have "Community user" have rights to delete, but have those "deletions" subject to normal-person override?

Comment: You know _most_ moderators aren't humans, right? Did you really thought a human being would actually _volunteer_ to clean up crap all day long?

Comment: @Yannis but they *pretend* to be

Comment: In the unlikely event that a question does get deleted by the Community ♦ user, which someone genuinely wants to keep, what's wrong with casting a moderator flag asking for it to be reinstated?

Comment: Related: [Why was this (native, not migrated) question deleted by Community?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175249/why-was-this-native-not-migrated-question-deleted-by-community)

Comment: @Shmuel Brin: I don't.

Comment: Unicorns feed on misery and poop joy.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, somebody has to notice it happened.  (This question came to my attention because of such a flag; how the flagger noticed the deletion I do not know.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I go through http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tools at times

Comment: The question can always be asked again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I agree, I think it's too much of an edge case to actually waste dev time to implement a solution for it.

If you want it undeleted, just flag for a moderator and they'll undelete it for you. If the question isn't crap as you say, there won't be any problems.

Comment: This. The need to reverse a Community deletion is just too rare to justify dev time.

Comment: I disagree. I think a developer's time is best spent improving the site however that may be. However, as I stated in my comment on the question, the question can always be asked again.

Comment: Still, your point about flagging for a moderator is well taken. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

[In July 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167500/should-questions-removed-automatically-for-inactivity-really-be-non-undeletable), this became [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Examples: I as a non-moderator participated in the undeletions of [this question](https://superuser.com/posts/1140617/revisions) and [this other one](https://superuser.com/posts/1137123/revisions), while I can't vote to undelete [this one](https://superuser.com/q/913055/380318), which was deleted by a real moderator.

Comment: I hope that community deletions for spam or offensiveness, which are attributed to Community but caused by six users, are *not* undeletable this way.  Does anybody happen to know?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Those are locked, so nobody except moderators can undelete them.

Comment: Oh duh, you're right.